# Как получать последнее изменение пути?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, сериализация

Всем привет. При сериализации столкнулся со следующей проблемой. За файлами в проекте у меня закреплены объекты класса Directory, в процессе работы программы, папки могут быть переименованы, но при вызове метода FullPath() у объекта DirInfo будет возвращен старый путь к папке. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я получал последний (изменение) путь к заданному каталогу.

Comment: [FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Нет, я знаю про существование этого класса и использую его для отслеживания изменений внутри как раз этого каталога. Для того, чтобы отслеживать переименование этого каталога нужно создавать вотчер у его родителя, но если папка будет перемещена, вотчер в дальнейшем уже не поможет, так как остальные изменения будут вне зоны его работы.

Comment: Ну так создайте второй watcher на ту папку, куда была директория перемещена. Других опций следить за папкой я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется тут проблема не в переименовании, а в самом процессе работы. Я не считаю правильным такое действие вообще без ведома самой программы. Что делать если перекинули файлы на тот свет? Вы и туда Watcher подкинете?

Comment: Ну с ведения самой программы вы можете всё конечно предусмотреть